# When submitting the form on the jsp page is running forever

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jstl, javabeans

When submitting the form on the jsp page below (cadastroPaciente.jsp), the System is running forever without returning any error.

I've already tested the connection alone in a Test Class and the Servlet without the connection to the database (only building the object and returning it to the screen) worked. But when I put it in the Servlet to save in the database it is running forever and does not save in database.

The buildpath has:

1. jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar
2. mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar

On the Console there's just this:

> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.39 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> built:          Oct 6 2020 14:11:46 UTC set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
> version number: 9.0.39.0 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
> Windows 10 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
> Version:            10.0 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> Architecture:          amd64 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
> Version:           16.0.1+9-24 set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
> Vendor:            Oracle Corporation set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> CATALINA_BASE:
> D:\Java\workspace-ee.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
> CATALINA_HOME:         D:\Java\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.39 set. 09,
> 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFO: Command line argument:
> -Dcatalina.base=D:\Java\workspace-ee.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\Java\Server\apache-tomcat-9.0.39
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument:
> -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Java\workspace-ee.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED set.
> 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
> log INFO: Command line argument:
> --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
> line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED set. 09,
> 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFO: Command line argument:
> --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFO: Command line argument:
> --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 set. 09, 2021
> 12:25:24 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
> INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO:
> Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.25] using APR version
> [1.7.0]. set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: APR
> capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
> random [true]. set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO:
> APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
> set. 09, 2021 12:25:24 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL INFO:
> OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020] set.
> 09, 2021 12:25:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
> Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] set. 09, 2021 12:25:25
> AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Server
> initialization in [565] milliseconds set. 09, 2021 12:25:25 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
> service [Catalina] set. 09, 2021 12:25:25 AM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
> Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.39] set. 09, 2021 12:25:25 AM
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
> ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] set. 09, 2021 12:25:25 AM
> org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
> [687] milliseconds

Can someone help me?

JSP Page:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Cadastro de Pacientes</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="PacienteServlet">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dados do Paciente</legend>
                <p>
                    <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
                    <input type="text" size="14" id="cpf" name="cpf" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                    <input type="text" size="20" id="nome" name="nome" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
                    <input type="number" size="3" id="idade" name="idade" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
                    <input type="text" size="20" id="telefone" name="telefone" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaBeans:

```
package entity;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Paciente implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String cpf;
    private String nome;
    private int idade;
    private String telefone;
    
    public Paciente(){}

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }
    
}
```

Servlet:

```
package servlet;

import entity.Paciente;
import persistence.PacienteDao;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class PacienteServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/PacienteServlet")
public class PacienteServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PacienteServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeURL("cadastroPaciente.jsp"));
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        
        try {
            
            Paciente paciente = new Paciente();
            PacienteDao dao = new PacienteDao(); 
            
            paciente.setCpf(request.getParameter("cpf"));
            paciente.setNome(request.getParameter("nome"));
            paciente.setIdade(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idade")));
            paciente.setTelefone(request.getParameter("telefone"));
           
            dao.efetuarCadastro(paciente);
                
            response.getWriter().append("Paciente cadastrado com sucesso!").append("<br />").append("<br />");
              
            response.getWriter().append("CPF: "+paciente.getCpf()).append("<br />");
            response.getWriter().append("Nome: "+paciente.getNome()).append("<br />");
            response.getWriter().append("Idade: "+paciente.getIdade()).append("<br />");
            response.getWriter().append("Telefone: "+paciente.getTelefone()).append("<br />").append("<br />");
           
            response.getWriter().append("<a href=\"cadastroPaciente.jsp\"> Clique aqui para voltar para o formulário </a>");
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            request.setAttribute("error", e.toString());
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            request.setAttribute("error", e.toString());
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
           
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Dao {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;
    CallableStatement call;
    
    public void abrirConexao() throws Exception{
        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avaliacaojavaee", "root", "admin");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }       
    }
    
    public void fecharConexao() throws Exception{       
        con.close();
    }
}
```

DAO Child:

```
package persistence;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import entity.Paciente;

public class PacienteDao extends Dao {
    
    public void efetuarCadastro(Paciente p) throws Exception {
        abrirConexao();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into paciente values(?,?,?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1, p.getCpf());
        stmt.setString(2, p.getNome());
        stmt.setInt(3, p.getIdade());
        stmt.setString(4, p.getTelefone());
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();
        fecharConexao();
    }
    
    public List<Paciente> listaPacientes() {
        try {
            abrirConexao();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from paciente");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            List<Paciente> lista = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Paciente p = new Paciente();
                p.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
                p.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                p.setIdade(rs.getInt("idade"));
                p.setTelefone(rs.getString("tel"));
                lista.add(p);
            }
            fecharConexao();
            return lista;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Paciente mostraPaciente(String cpf) throws Exception {

            abrirConexao();
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from paciente where cpf = ? ");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();           
            Paciente p = null;
            if (rs.next()) {
                p = new Paciente();
                p.setCpf(rs.getString("cpf"));
                p.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                p.setIdade(rs.getInt("idade"));
                p.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));                
            }
            fecharConexao();
            return p;
    }

}
```

Comment: *the System is running forever* - how do you know?  What debugging have you done?

Comment: It gets the loading symbol on the tab of the page, and running. And the messages I posted on doPost do not appear. And it does not register in the database either. What could be wrong?

Comment: I am a bit curious. You have a line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());` if an exception is thrown when you open a connection. Where do you expect this to be written out? Your application does not seem to be a Swing application. Isn't it better to log this instead? Not saying that this is the exact issue, but if this does not get written out you are catching an important exception without knowing anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! **It needed to include the mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar in the library (in the lib folder), below the WEB-INF**. But thank you for the
DanielBarbarian because he pointed out an important subject about the JOptionPane. Actually my application is not a swing application so the JOptionPane doesn't make sense. This was because I copied it from somewhere else that was probably a Swing application.

Comment: It's not a topic, it's a question :) You can [accept your answer](/help/accepted-answer) after the minimum time has elapsed.